# Метод класса ruby R2Point, описывающий точки на плоскости.Требуется найти расстояние между двумя точками

Tags: ruby

Где ошибка?

```
class R2Point                          
  def initialize(x, y)                 
    @x, @y = x, y                      
  end

  def dist(a)

    Math.sqrt((a.x-@x)**2 + (a.y-@y)**2)
  end                                  
  def R2Point.dist(a, b)               
    Math.sqrt((a.x-b.x)**2 + (a.y-b.y)**2)  
  end                                  
end                                   
p1 = R2Point.new(1,2)                  
p2 = R2Point.new(-1,-2)                
puts p1.dist(p2)                       
puts R2Point.dist(p1, p2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Дело в том, что инстанс-переменные, которые начинаются с символа @, не доступны за пределами объекта. Такие переменные доступны только в инстанс-методах объекта. Чтобы сделать их доступными нужно либо ввести методы-реадеры

```
class R2Point
  def x
    @x
  end
  def y
    @y
  end
  ...
end
```

или можно поступить короче, воспользовавшись attr_reader, который создас методы-реадары автоматически

```
class R2Point
  attr_reader :x, :y
  ...
end
```

После этого ваш пример заработает.